# Copying a subset of files (names contained in a vector) from one folder to another folder in R

Tags: r, file, copy, file-copying

Ok, so I know similar questions were asked in the past, I checked them all and tried every bit of code I found and I am desperate

Here is my problem:

I have 2 folders, let's call them "A" and "B". Both are directly on my desktop. B is an empty folder that I want to fill with files from "A", but not all the files. "A" contains a total of 6000 files, and I only need 5000 specific ones to be copied to B. I don't need to delete or rename, really only copy.

The tocopy2 vector was created by taking a dataframe that had a column with all the names I need inside, then using list files I found them directly in my folder A, and then by a simple subset I stored them in the tocopy2 objects. I also tried taking directly the columns and storing it in a vector, but the results were the same

For now, I have a vector (class: character) that contains the specific full names of the 5000 files I need to copy. I also generated a second vector corrector containing their full paths in case it could come in handy. I have tried a looot of different variations of code using the file.copy() function, but it always end up returning FALSE for all the files or other funky errors.

tocopy is a vector containing all the files name
paths is a vector containing all the paths

```
current= "C:/Users/pathtoA"
new= "C:/Users/pathtoB"
```

I'm sorry I have to censor the paths as i working with confidential data!

***Edit following useful comments***

Tocopy is a character vector containing file names, the file are .dcm files

Ex: tocopy= “file1.dcm” “file2.dcm” etc.

The paths for A and B are proper paths with enough / between elements ! I just can’t share their exact name as they are on a secure computer !

Thanks for the help

***end of EDIT***

Here is everything I tried so far

```
file.copy(from = paste0("C:/Users/pathtoA", tocopy), to = paste0("C:/Users/pathtoB", tocopy)) 
#returns only FALSE

file.copy(paths, to= "C:/Users/pathtoB") 
#Returns only false

file.copy(
  tocopy,
  from="C:/Users/pathtoA", 
  to="C:/Users/pathtoB", 
  recursive = TRUE, 
  overwrite= TRUE,
  copy.mode = TRUE, copy.dates = TRUE
) 
#Error in file.copy...unused argument (copy.dates = TRUE)

file.copy (tocopy2, from = current, to = new)
#Error in file.copy(tocopy, from = current, to = new) : invalid 'overwrite' argument

file.copy (tocopy2, from = current, to = new, overwrite = TRUE) 
#Error in recursive && to %in% from : invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'
```

If someone is able to find a solution I would be the most happy person and the most grateful!

Thanks in advance everyone

Comment: Since you haven't shared any examples of what `tocopy` looks like I can't be sure, but my best guess is that you are missing a `/` in your path when you paste things together. If you run `paste0("C:/Users/pathtoA", tocopy[1:3])` does it look like a proper filepath with `/` after `A` and before the file name?

Comment: Often `file.path()` is recommended over `paste` for working with file names as it takes care of things like that automatically. I'd suggest `file.copy(from = file.path("C:/Users/pathtoA", tocopy), to = file.path("C:/Users/pathtoB", tocopy))`. You may also want to set `showWarnings = TRUE` as the warnings might help understand what is going wrong.

Comment: As for the errors on your last couple attempts, if you look at the `?file.copy` help page it's first 3 arguments are `from`, `to`, and `overwrite`. When you run a command like `file.copy(tocopy2, from = current, to = new)` you are clearly specifying `from = current` and `to = new`, the first argument you don't name will therefore be assumed to be `overwrite`, so your command is interpreted as `overwrite = tocopy2`, which obviously doesn't make sense. In your next attempt, you set `overwrite = TRUE` so the next argument in the function definition is guessed for your unnamed first argument...

Comment: ...Lesson being, pay attention to the arguments expected by the function. The only place `tocopy2` makes sense to go is as part of the `from` argument. Putting it first and a giving something else to the `from =` argument will not work. (And for the attempt before that, there is an argument named `copy.date` without the `s`, but there is not an argument named `copy.dates`)